# How to efficiently parse complex nested json using pyspark?

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark

I have this type of json:

```
root
 |-- Culture: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- IdType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 0318e300-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-dd86d1b56df5: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- IdType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- 0d05acd5-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-e8a00cfabe08: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- IdType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- 2143365f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3ba390401bf1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- IdType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Description: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- IdType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Source: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- Source: string (nullable = true)
```

My target is:

1. efficiently flatten it and grab GUID/Id/IdType/Description information under each guid
2. make a dataframe using pyspark with following columns:

Id, IdType, Description, ParentGuid

I'm currently using a brute force method with three for loops to go to each level. But it's very slow and easy to break my synapse cluster.

Any idea is appreciated!

Thank you.